# Setting divider location on a JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to have 3 resizable horizontally JPanels. It works fine but I can not set the position of the first JSlitPane: `sp.setDividerLocation(.3);` doesn't work.

```
public class JSplitPanelProva extends JFrame {

        public JSplitPanelProva() {
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
            leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
            centerPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
            rightPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, centerPanel);
            JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, sp, rightPanel);

            sp.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            sp2.setOneTouchExpandable(true);


            this.add(sp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            this.setSize(1000, 600);
            this.setVisible(true);

            sp.setDividerLocation(.3);
            sp2.setDividerLocation(.6);
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new JSplitPanelProva();

        }

    }
```

I get this:
[image]
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
        sp.setDividerLocation(.3);
        sp2.setDividerLocation(.6);
```

To:

```
    sp2.setDividerLocation(.6);
    ActionListener splitListener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sp.setDividerLocation(.3);
        }
    };
    Timer t = new Timer(200, splitListener);
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
```

And it will work as expected. The delay gives time for the GUI to recalculate sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the `setDividerLocation(double proportionalLocation)` method says:

> If the split pane is not correctly realized and on screen, this method
>   will have no effect (new divider location will become (current size *
>   proportionalLocation) which is 0).

What you can do instead is using the `setDividerLocation(int location)` method like this:

```
sp.setDividerLocation(300);
sp2.setDividerLocation(600);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 3 things need to happen:

1. The divider location can't be set until the frame is visible
2. Setting the location of the second split pane needs to be done first
3. Setting the location of the first split pane needs to be added to the end of on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`

The following code will accomplish all 3:

```
this.setVisible(true);

sp2.setDividerLocation(.6);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        sp.setDividerLocation(.3);
    }
});
```

Note: all Swing components should be create on the EDT. So you should also be using the following to create the frame:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        new JSplitPaneProva();
    }
});
```